# How to pass NSManagedObject into ECSliding

Tags: nsmanagedobject, ecslidingviewcontroller

I don't know if anyone has asked this question or perhaps I have overlooked. Please accept my apologies.

I have a LoginViewController in front of InitialSlidingView. How can I pass NSManagedObjectContext into InitialSlidingView and subsequently to any NavigationTopView? I have NSManagedObjectContext and NSManagedObjectModel in AppDelegate.

Thanks.
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a `NSManagedObject` property on your view controllers. Then you can set this property on the view controllers the need it or end up passing it along.